# Asp net core - can't see new added icon in browser

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

We are running an ASP NET CORE MVC service (.Net core 2.2) that acts as our client.

I've added a simple HTML with an img tag to one of our views.

```
    <a class='icon-suspend-wait txt-color-orange'>
        <img src = '/Content/img/icons/icon-suspend-wait.png' alt='Waiting for suspend' />
        <span class='vertical-middle'>Waiting for suspend</span>
    </a>
```

Now, I've added a new png file named "icon-suspend-wait.png" under
Content\img\icons folder

[icons folder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhVUj.png)

When I navigate to the website I can see the added HTML part but not the icon.

So I opened chrome devTools AND under the "Elements" tab, I can see the new HTML part (the ).

[elements section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnQqK.png)

But under the "Source" tab I can't see the icon I've added:

[source section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWQfT.png)

When I try to open the icon link in a new tab from the "Elements" tab, I get the following error:

[404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhofR.png)

What i tried to do:

1. Clean and recompile the project.
2. Hard refresh for the browser.
3. Disable the cache from the DevTools (Network -> Disable Cache).

Nothing seems to work.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve files outside of web root,you need to add the following configuration in StartUp.cs:

```
...
using System.IO;
namespace ClientSideDemo5
public class Startup
{
  ...
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
           ...
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
          Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Content")),
                RequestPath = "/Content"
            });

            app.UseRouting();

            ...
        }
}
```

img:

```
<img src = '~/Content/img/icons/icon-suspend-wait.png' alt='Waiting for suspend' />
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I only added a new icon to an existing directory. so "Content" folder is already configured and I can see all other icons in that folder